# How to Load commands into your powershell profile to run on starting powershell

Tags: scripting, powershell, exchange-2010, profile

I have found a way to load exchange 2010 powershell into powershell running on a windows xp workstation, however there are a few commands that need to run.
I was wondering how I could load them into a profile somehow.
These are the commands that I need to run before I can do any of the exchange things such as Get-Mailbox.

COMMAND 1 $session = New-PSSession -Configurationname Microsoft.Exchange –ConnectionUri http://servername/powershell -Credential $user

(it prompts you for a username and p/word then the next command)

COMMAND 2 Import-PSSession $session

Then I am able to run exchange 2010 commands such as Get-Mailbox.
Anyway I can load these so that when I click on the powershell shortcut they preload the importing of exchange commands.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add them to your [powershell profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: How do I do that?